# Is it possible to create a 4 inch by 4 inch channel through concrete using acid?

Tags: acid-base, home-experiment

I'm trying to figure out a way to eat through concrete without damage pex tubing inside (its a radiant heated slab). Is there any way using some type of acid (hydrofluoric, muriatic ) to eat a 4 inch wide, 4 inch deep, and 71 foot long channel through the slab that could be tapped out with a blunt chisel? Pex tubing is resistant to most acids so it would not be damaged.

Also, this needs to be cost effective (under $1000).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Offhand, this seems dangerous to the structural integrity of the slab, because the acid would follow the pore structure of the concrete and weaken the wrong places.

However, *concrete cutting saw rental* is available; e.g. [United Rentals](http://www.unitedrentals.com/en/catalog/equipment-tools/concrete-masonry/concrete-saw-13-hp-propelled)
and http://www6.homedepot.com/tool-truck-rental/Walk_Behind_Concrete_Saw_14/MK-CX3/index.html. Two 45-degree cuts ~6" or deeper should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed as much since I had never heard of it being done.  Now I know why.

Comment: I'd be worried about willy-nilly cutting such a slab as the OP described. My father-in-law's house was on such a slab. The heated slab had dried out the soil under the slab and the soil has shrunk away from the slab. he could see an open space between the slab and the soil under much of the house.